# How to get a warning whenever a given function is imported, even indirectly?

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, static-code-analysis, dependency-graph

In my current TypeScript/Node.js project, we have implemented an internal cache module that we are progressively getting rid of.

To achieve that, I would like to progressively reduce the parts of the codebase that can import that module, directly or indirectly. And to be warned during development whenever we violate that rule.

Example:

- `users.ts` is allowed to import `cache.ts`
- `domain.ts` imports `users.ts`, but it’s not allowed to import `cache.ts` (even thru `users.ts`), so we want to be warned about that.

Do you know a way to enforce that rule with TSC, Eslint, or another static code analysis tool?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I know is the [eslint-plugin-boundaries](https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/eslint-plugin-boundaries) project. It might be worth refactoring your modules for the cache so you can use some of these rules.

Failing that, writing a custom ESLint rule is fairly straight forward so long as you've got a set of rules you can apply to the AST.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to remove your cache module, I would recommend to use `@deprecated` jsdoc statement. This way, you will be warned every time you want to use it in new development.
In addition to that, you can use [an ESLint plugin](https://github.com/AlexMost/eslint-plugin-deprecate) to warn

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Romain!
If you know a ESLint plugin that can warn about transitive usage of deprecated dependencies (i.e. warn in function C about calling function B, if B relies on a deprecated function A), I'm all ears!